# Template not updated (but model is) after authentication with Google

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-template, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I have a simple model displaying the email of my user, ang I'm using Google to authenticate.

Here is the code I wrote for authentication:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then((args) => {
  this.user = { email: args.wc.hg }
  console.log(this.user);
});
```

The console.log is correctly displaying the email but the template is not updated and I still see nothing on the browser: `{{user?.email}}`.

An other point, I just replaced the authentication with a simple promise :

```
new Promise<string>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('email'), 10000)).then(data => this.user = { email: data });
```

This is working and my template is displaying `email`.

I cannot see the difference between the resolution of these two promises, but obviously there is one.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any log /error on console.  Can you wrap this.user = {} in a setTimeout and see if that works. I suspect this is not correct in your handler.  Can you print 'typeof this' on console. I think it might point to window

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is correctly referring to my component. This is what I checked with the mocked promise. I guess micronyks' answer below is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because code it running out of angular2 framework.What you can do is, you can check change detection manually using below code,

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';    

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {  //<----- injection
  }

  someMethod() {

    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then((args) => {
       this.user = { email: args.wc.hg }
        console.log(this.user);

         this.cdr.detectChanges();              //<----Note this...
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Good this is working thanks a lot. Can you explain why we have to call `detectChanges()` if the code is running out of Angular2? Or give us a link?

Comment: please check this  http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Basically application state change can be caused by three things:
Events - click, submit, …
`XHR - Fetching data from a remote server
Timers - setTimeout(), setInterval()`
They are all asynchronous. Which brings us to the conclusion that, basically whenever some asynchronous operation has been performed, our application state might have changed. This is when someone needs to tell Angular to update the view.

Comment: I hope this is enough to make you aware of using changedetection. isn't it?